# UILabel inside a View scrolling being truncated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a `UILabel` to scroll text inside a small view, this scrolls and then repeats after some time.
What happens now, is the length of the text, becomes truncated, so instead of the full name showing, it shows xxxxxxxxxx then .. at the end, is there a way to extend it, so it shows the entire text without truncating?

```
-(void)text_1_Move_animetion
{
    text_1_lable.frame = CGRectMake(text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.origin.y, text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 animations:^{
        text_1_lable.frame = CGRectMake(-text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.origin.y, text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.size.height);
    }];
    [self performSelector:@selector(text_1_repet) withObject:self afterDelay:8.0];


}
-(void)text_1_repet
{
    text_1_lable.frame = CGRectMake(text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.origin.y, text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.size.height);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 animations:^{
        text_1_lable.frame = CGRectMake(-text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.origin.y, text_1_lable.frame.size.width, text_1_lable.frame.size.height);
    }];


    [self performSelector:@selector(text_1_Move_animetion) withObject:self afterDelay:8.0];
}
```

If I set the linebreak within the .xib file to `break` it does not truncate with a .. It shows a bit more, but then cuts off towards the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the width of the string and see if the width is greater than label.bounds.size.width

NSString UIKit Additions has several methods for computing the size of the string with a specific font. However, if you have a minimumFontSize for your label that allows the system to shrink the text down to that size. You may want to use [sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html) in that case.